# SQL - Missing Keyword in GRANT SELECT ACCESS to User

Tags: select, sqlplus, sql-grant

I'm trying to `GRANT SELECT ACCESS` to a user to retrieve the details of the table `PRESCRIPTION` prescribed by its `DID` (doctor ID) 3`286409`

This is what I typed:

```
 GRANT SELECT ON PRESCRIPTION WHERE DID = '3286409' TO SYSTEM;
```

I got this error *missing keyword* pointed under `WHERE`

I even tried googling and searching for any examples but none to find..
Note that `DID` is a `VARCHAR2` datatype.

If anyone knows how to help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not come accross that syntex before (grant select with a where clause) so not sure if you can do it that way, but you could create a view for the particuler DID value instead and then grant select on that.